# PHP DOMDocument : How to parse custom XML/RSS tag names with COLONS?

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument, conditional-operator

I have the below RSS to parse, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:x-wr="http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/prod/Apple_Comp_628d9d8459c556fa#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x-example="http://www.example.com/rss/x-example" xmlns:x-microsoft="http://schemas.microsoft.com/x-microsoft" xmlns:xCal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xcal" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>About Apples</title>
            <author>David K. Lowie</title>
            <description>Some description about apples</description>
            <xCal:description>This is the full description about apples</xCal:description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>About Oranges</title>
            <author>Marry L. Jones</title>
            <description>Some description about oranges</description>
            <xCal:description>This is the full description about oranges</xCal:description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

In PHP, i parse it something like:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load( "http://www.example.com/books.rss" );

foreach( $rss->getElementsByTagName("item") as $node ) {
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue,
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName("author")->item(0)->nodeValue,
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName("description")->item(0)->nodeValue,
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName("xCal:description")->item(0)->nodeValue,
}
```

I can read **everything except** the `xCal:description` node there. (The node names are exactly like that: `description` and the `xCal:description`.)

1. **How to parse (read) the nodes like** `xCal:description`
2. Is it because of the similar node names, like: `description` and the `xCal:description` ?

*(I can't change the RSS source since it's not under my control.)*

Please kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getElementsByTagNameNS()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php):

```
$node->getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xcal", "description")->item(0)->nodeValue
```

Comment: @夏期劇場 `echo $node->getElementsByTagNameNS($node->lookupNamespaceURI('xCal'), "description")->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: Hi `code-kobold` and `splash58`, thanks both for the help. Can you guys please help me on this one too please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096183/php-domdocument-how-to-parse-xml-rss-with-custom-tag-names (Thanks all)

Answer (score 1):

While using the namespace aware variants of the DOM methods is a correct answer, you might want to take a look at Xpath. It is a much more comfortable way to fetch data from a DOM.

For the Xpath expression, you can register own prefixes for the namespaces as needed.

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load("http://www.example.com/books.rss");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($rss);
$xpath->registerNamespace('xc', 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xcal');

foreach($xpath->evaluate("//item") as $item) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item), "\n";
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(author)', $item), "\n";
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $item), "\n";
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(xc:description)', $item), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
About Apples
David K. Lowie
Some description about apples
This is the full description about apples
About Oranges
Marry L. Jones
Some description about oranges
This is the full description about oranges
```

Comment: Thanks much. This is quite neat. Can you please also help on the another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096183/php-domdocument-how-to-parse-xml-rss-with-custom-tag-names , please? :)